# Switching from version 4.3.11.Final to 5.0.1.Final causes compilation error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-5.x

I am trying to upgrade my Hibernate version from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately by compiling I get the following error.

> TestDao.java:[5,25] cannot find symbol
>
> [ERROR] symbol:   class Transactional
>
> [ERROR] location: package javax.transaction

I have been struggling with it for over an hour now.

I have tried adding package `spring-tx` but it did not help.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Did anyone face a similar issue?

Comment: Are you using spring or jee7 transactional annotation?

Comment: I am using `javax.transaction.Transactional` so the JEE7 one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`spring-tx` gives you `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`, but your error message clearly states that you're trying to apply `javax.transaction.Transactional`.

[Searching for `javax.transaction.Transactional` on Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3Ajavax.transaction.Transactional) shows a number of candidates; either `javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:1.2` or `javax:javaee-api:7.0` looks like a reasonable option.

It appears that [the POM for Hibernate 4.3](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.pom) did include a dependency on the JBoss-specific version of the `javax.transaction` package but that it was removed in Hibernate 5.0, presumably because it had been standardized and including a hard dependency on a specific package could result in problems at runtime.

Comment: How come that it works smoothly with version 4.3.11.Final?

Comment: So you just switched to spring annotation or did you add a new dependency in your pom ?

Comment: @TheBakker I just added a new dependency in my `pom.xml`

Comment: Thank you, javax.transaction-api:1.2 ?
Did you had any other issue then during the migration ?